Connect as Reconnectable client in MQ uniform clusters, application hosted in Open liberty uses MQ adapter to connect MQ Qmgr
We require application hosted in Open Liberty (22.x) which connects MQ qmgr(9.3.x) via MQ adapter 9.2.x to connect as Reconnectable client to MQ uniform clusters for Application rebalancing.
Please suggest any JMS connection factory settings or Adapter settings to achieve this.
Thank you
We tried clientReconnectOptions along with ccdt and  connection namelist which didn't helped.
This is the CCDT

    {
    "channel": [{
        "name": "UNIFORM.SVRCONN",
        "clientConnection": {
          "connection": [{
            "host": "Host1",
            "port": 51000
           },{
            "host": "Host2",
            "port": 51000
           },{
            "host": "Host3",
            "port": 51000
            }],
          "queueManager": "ANY_QM"
        },
       "transmissionSecurity":
      {
        "cipherSpecification": "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
      },
        "type": "clientConnection"
        },
        {
            "name": "UNIFORM.SVRCONN",
            "clientConnection":
            {
                "connection":
                [
                    {
                        "host": "Host1",
                        "port": 51000
                    }
                ],
                "queueManager": "QM1"
            },
      "transmissionSecurity":
      {
        "cipherSpecification": "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
      },
            "type": "clientConnection"
        },
        {
            "name": "UNIFORM.SVRCONN",
            "clientConnection":
            {
                "connection":
                [
                    {
                        "host": "Host2",
                        "port": 51000
                    }
                ],
                "queueManager": "QM2"
            },
      "transmissionSecurity":
      {
        "cipherSpecification": "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
      },
            "type": "clientConnection"
        },
        {
            "name": "UNIFORM.SVRCONN",
            "clientConnection":
            {
                "connection":
                [
                    {
                        "host": "Host3",
                        "port": 51000
                    }
                ],
                "queueManager": "QM3"
            },
     "transmissionSecurity":
      {
        "cipherSpecification": "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"
      },
            "type": "clientConnection"
        }
   ]
}



Is there any reason why you are using a 9.2.x adapter to connect to a 9.3.x server? I don't think anything before 9.2.3 client / adapter had uniform cluster capability.

Adapter version wmq.jmsra-9.2.3.0.rar

With uniform clusters, you only need to use a CCDT and not a connection name list (not to be confused with a connection list, which will be a part of your CCDT). Using both may be causing a clash. Provide just the CCDTURL in your server.xml file like so:
<properties.wmqjmsra 
  ccdtURL="${CCDT_URL}" 
  clientReconnectOptions="ANY" 
  queueManager="${<name of queue manager group name in CCDT>}"
  userName="${<your app username>}" 
/>

--- Update ---
Based on the CCDT you have provided, I would expect to see the following in your server.xml
queueManager="*ANY_QM"


You shouldn't provide anything here that is already provided in the CCDT.
Also, although 9.2.3 is supported for MQ adapters, it might be a good idea to use at least 9.3.

Thanks sjain for your response, we tried as you mentioned still app rebalancing is not happening, Application connecting without reconnect option

Please post your CCDT.

See updated answer based on your CCDT

Hi JoshMC, CCDT posted

Hi @sjain, Yes using ANY_QM, connectivity is working fine but it connects to first available sever, then the application rebalancing is not happening. For example i can't see connection option MQCNO_RECONNECT in conntag of application, so couldn't see app rebalancing in uniform clusters.     BALANCED(NOTAPPLIC)    IMMREASN(NOTRECONN)

Are you using *ANY_QM or ANY_QM ?  Note the *

@chughts yes  *ANY_QM

What you have should work, wondering whether you need to bump the adapter you are using.

The requested CCDT has been added to the question.
